# Install TFS 2018 without Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

I am installing TFS 2018.

I am wondering if it's possible to install it without installing the Reporting Services and the Analysis Services?

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's easy. During the configuration phase, just skip the configuration for Reporting.

The end-result is that you don't have the Analysis Cube and the old Reports (which are being replaced with [Analytics Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/analytics/what-is-analytics?view=azure-devops) anyway)